# Log only specific query in magento

Tags: magento

I want to log all the query that affect only specific table. For example `catalog_product_flat_1`.
So if query makes `update`, `delete` or `insert` operation to this table it should be logged. It cаused by deleting column `sku` from time to time from this table and I want to find out the reason.

Comment: Did you manage to find the solution of this?

Comment: Question is answered on magento.stackexchange: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14900/debug-only-specific-query-in-magento